# Access custom Increment ("yy" & 0000)

Tags: ms-access, increment, sequential-number

I have just dived into access for the first time.  Pretty easy So far.    I have created a form for my employees to use to create to job tickets.  What I am trying to do now, is to number the tickets in the format 17-0001, 17-0002 etc automatically. This number is the unique identifier for all jobs, and is what will be primarily used in the future for queries.   I found I could do this with autonumber prefix but I see thats not a good idea.  In  addition to the sequencing,  I also need the numbering to start over each year.  SO jan 1 2 018 first job would be 18-0001.  I beleive i need to use dmax to accomplish this, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: All I can say is: this is a bad idea. Having a string as a record identifier will slow down all queries linking on it, needing to calculate a `DMax` when inserting a query will also slow that down by a lot depending on how many queries you have, it will complicate any future query (you can use a default, but any custom insert query will need to calculate that default for any record), and it will introduce possible concurrency issues on insert (if two users insert a record at the same time). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: "the way  its always been"  is the best answer. but also, we currently export the data in that format for use in accounting software. what if instead of using a string as an identifier, you run a script that finds the next number and inserts it as text into the table. this could also prevent duplicates. i would have no idea how to code this, but it may get me going down the right path. we are talking about 1000 entries per year.

Comment: What access version? You might be able to add table triggers for this job.

Comment: access 2016. 

thanks for the replies btw